# How to install Firefox 28 on Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on project in which I am using GWT and Java technology. My firefox version is 44 and when I try to run project into development mode. 
Firefox says to install plug-in. I installed plug-in as well but its not working. Then finally it says to down graded Firefox version.

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 as OS. Does someone have any idea how to install Firefox28 on Ubuntu 14.4.
I read one article as well but its not working.

```
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/how-to-install-previous-versions-of-firefox-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/
```

Comment: Please refer to solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231764/how-to-install-previous-firefox-version/40231765#40231765

Answer (score 0):

go into synaptic and highlight your installed version of firefox.
click "package"..and then click "force version". there is a version 28 in there.

if you don't want it automatically updated, click "package" again and "lock version"